# How to convert Japanese date into English date format?

Tags: java, android, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I set Japanese date using Locale (e.g. 21 11月 2016) in my android app. But, I want to send that date into "dd-MM-yyyy" (e.g. 21-11-2016) format to my APIs.

When I try to do this I get below exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String

Below is my code :

```
public String convertDate(String date) {
    System.out.println("......ORIGINAL DATE....... " + date); // ......ORIGINAL DATE....... 21 11月 2016
    String myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, new Locale(getMyLocale())); //Japanese locale is set but tried english too
    System.out.println("......CONVERTED DATE....... " + sdf.format(date)); //should be 21-11-2016 but getting above error
    return sdf.format(new Date(date));
}
```

Moreover, for US/English Locale it works fine but for Japanese I am getting this error.

Comment: as you are parsing a String then you should use `parse` not `format`  Also the format of `21 11月 2016` is not `dd-MMM-yyyy` - try parsing with format of `dd MM月 yyyy` if that is really your string

Comment: See dd-MM-yyyy is the format in which I need it but on text label I set date like 21 Nov 2016

Comment: And for parse I get this error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016年11月 21日" (at offset 11)

Comment: call `java.util.Locale.getDefault()` instead of `new Locale(getMyLocale())`

Comment: Doing same. See what getMyLocale() returns "return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();"

Comment: If you want to convert StringA to StringB then your need two different formatters  `Date a = sdf1.parse("2016年11月 21日");  sdf2.format (a);`  sdf1 will input mask sdf2 will output mask

Comment: Do you mean to create 2 DateFormat's, English & Japan resp.?

Comment: @VVB you can create this

Comment: What is your input date format?

Comment: @KNeerajLal Japanese...

Comment: Did it but getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "21 11月 2016" (at offset 0)

Comment: @VVB So you don't know the input dateformat? (other than that its japanese)

Comment: @VVB Edit your Question to show *exact* examples of specific input strings, specific formatting pattern, and specific output results or specific error. Otherwise you are wasting our time.

Answer (score 4):

You need two formatters as below

```
    String in = "2016年11月 21日";   // really a space here?
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy年MM月 dd日");
    Date d1 = sdf1.parse(in);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy");

    System.out.println(sdf2.format(d1));
```

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

You are using the troublesome old legacy date-time classes supplanted by java.time classes.

Define a `DateTimeFormatter` object to match the pattern of your input strings and specify a `Locale` for Japan. Parse input string into a `LocalDate` object. Call `LocalDate.parse`.

Define a `DateTimeFormatter` object to match your desired output. Call `LocalDate::format` to generate a string you desire.

This has been documented *many* times already in StackOverflow. Please search to find example code and further discussion.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).